# Is it possible to show button to display a link on email templates in Salesforce

Tags: javascript, email-template, html, vf-email-template, salesforce-survey

I have a classic email template where I am sending a link to a survey invitation to users. Due to some privacy laws, the link should only show up on the email, when the user clicks on a button 'Ok to take survey' on the email.
Is it possible to achieve this with HTML or Visualforce email templates? Is there any alternative solution for this?
I also checked the Outlook documentation and it was mentioned that it doesn't support some HTML components. Please let me know if it can be achieved in some other way.

This is the HTML code snippet:

```
<button id="myButton" onclick="showButton()"> Okay to Take Survey </button>

<div id="pinkButtonContainer" style="display: none;">
 <a href="link_to_survey">
  <img alt="Pink Button" src="image_source_path" title="Pink Button" />
 </a>
</div>


<script>

  function showButton() {

    var pinkButtonContainer = document.getElementById("pinkButtonContainer");

    pinkButtonContainer.style.display = "block"; // show the pink button

  }

</script>
```

Comment: Mail clients don't want to support interactivity - see [Mailchimp's guidelines](https://mailchimp.com/help/limitations-of-html-email/) for example. Have the button go to a web page that then exposes the survey link. The web page can be an Experience site